# Fink installation: After installation (I believe): -bash: fink: command not found

Tags: command-line, macos, bash, fink

I want to install "fink"to my new MacBookpro, 
when

```
The core packages have been updated. You should now update the other packages
using commands like 'fink update-all'.
```

I assumed that fink has been successfully installed, but when I tried to follow the instruction call the command:

```
fink update-all

-bash: fink: command not found
```

Is this expected? 
Or did I do something wrong? 
Any information is needed to do the trouble shooting, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Check that this line

```
. /sw/bin/init.sh
```

has been added in either `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile`. If the search comes up empty, then add the line to one of these files. If you are not sure which file you should use, then add it to `.bash_profile`. Open a new terminal session and `init.sh` will modify your PATH variable.

Comment: I added this line to `.bash_profile`, and `source .bash_profile`,`fink update-all`, `Password:
Scanning package description files..........
Information about 10116 packages read in 1 seconds.
No packages to install.` I guess it worked, TKS!